# Calling elasticsearch url with server name fails

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elastic search 5.5.1 installed with xpack. I've created an index and used fscrawler to populate it. Via Postman, I perform a GET on a url in the form `localhost:9200/myindex/_search?q="William"` and it all works fine. If I change localhost to the ip 127.0.0.1 it still works. If I change it to the servername then postman comes back with could not get any response. All of this from the same server that everything has been installed on.

I need to get it to work using the server name since I obviously want to make the call from other machines. What do I need to do to make it recognize the server name?

Comment: How did you get server name?

Comment: Also to call from other machines why not to use IP?

Comment: If I use the actual IP of the machine e.g. 10.128.128.114 then use postman either locally or from a different physical box I receive an error from postman that it could not get a response. On the Local Machine if I use the localhost ip of 127.0.0.1 then it works.

Comment: If you use ip from the same machine does it works? because it sounds to me as firewall issue

Comment: Have you added 9200 to firewall whitelist? (but still without firewall rule it should work within the same machine...)

Comment: No it doesn't. So Elasticsearch and postman are on the same physical machine. If I use localhost or 127.0.0.1 then it works. if I change this to be 10.128.128.114 still on the same physical server it fails. Consequently moving to another server will fail for sure if it cannot do it locally. The machine name is myserver and if I use that, it too fails.

Comment: its windows or linux?

Comment: windows server 2012 R2

Comment: Try to disable firewall and do call again

Comment: What is the value of the `http.host` setting in `elasticsearch.yml`? [See this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings_2)

Comment: @val I have set http.host: 10.128.128.114 and refreshed postman, but still the same issue

Comment: @val actually that did it. I needed to stop and start the elasticsearch service.

Comment: Yep, if you modify the config you need to restart the server. Glad you figured it out.